# When did "Budapest" take place in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-widow, hawkeye

In the MCU, a mission took place in Budapest in which Clint Barton (Hawkeye) was sent to take out Natasha Romanoff. I believe it was also the mission in which Natasha was sent to kill Dreykov and his daughter. However, I've never seen a date or even a year for when the mission took place. **When did the Budapest mission take place?** I know:

- It must have been before the events of *Iron Man 2* (2009), because it is Natasha's first appearance in the MCU and she works for S.H.I.E.L.D.
- It was likely in the early 2000s, due to the early events of *Black Widow* taking place in 1995 and Natasha being 11 at the time.
- Natasha was grown up at the time of the mission.

**To be clear, I am ***not*** looking for the events of Budapest, but the date it occurred.**

Comment: Is that a duplicate? I don’t see anything in the answers that determines when it happened.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite seems to me when/if that information comes available it would be an edit or new answer on that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 2008

According to [a deleted scene](https://youtu.be/sqKY0-WPoDE?t=33) in the film *Black Widow*, Natasha was in the city "*eight years ago*". Since we know that the events of the main film take place in [2016](https://comicbook.com/movies/news/when-does-black-widow-take-place-mcu-timeline-kevin-feige-explains-setting-civil-war-infinity-war/) (e.g. between *Civil War* and *Infinity War*), this means that the [Budapest Mission](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Budapest_Operation) must have taken place in **2008**.

> **Yelena:** *And you drove us into a cage*
>
> **BW:** *This gate wasn't here **eight years ago***

Comment: Well, seems legit